# Principal component analysis ('function' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: machine-learning, python, pca

I am trying to use a principal component analysis to determine the most important features in my dataset. When I run the code below, I receive an error saying "PCA object is not subscribable." I have attempted to add various arguments into the PCA() function but receive the same error any time.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca =   PCA()
x_pca = pca.fit(X_train)

def myplot(score,coeff,labels=None):
    xs = score[:,0]
    ys = score[:,0]
    n = coeff.shape[0]
    scalex = 1.0/(xs.max() - xs.min())
    scaley = 1.0/(ys.max() - ys.min())
    plt.scatter(xs * scalex,ys * scaley, c = y)
    for i in range(n):
        plt.arrow(0, 0, coeff[i,0], coeff[i,1],color = 'r',alpha = 0.5)
        if labels is None:
            plt.text(coeff[i,0]* 1.15, coeff[i,1] * 1.15, "Var"+str(i+1), color = 'g', ha = 'center', va = 'center')
        else:
            plt.text(coeff[i,0]* 1.15, coeff[i,1] * 1.15, labels[i], color = 'g', ha = 'center', va = 'center')
plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)
plt.xlabel("PC{}".format(1))
plt.ylabel("PC{}".format(2))
plt.grid()

#Call the function. Use only the 2 PCs.
myplot(x_pca[:,0:2],np.transpose(pca.components_[0:2, :]))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please note that PCA stands for **Principal** Component Analysis

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the fact that you are trying to index the `PCA` object when calling `x_pca[:,0:2]`. I am not sure what type of values you are expecting to pass to your `myplot` function, but calling `PCA.fit` does not return an array of values but simply the `PCA` instance itself (see also [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit)). If you are looking to use the values on the new principal components you can use the `transform` method after having fitted the `PCA` object, or use the [`fit_transform` method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit_transform) to fit and transform the data in a single step.